# combining techeles views - tarti dsatri?

Tags: halacha, machlokes, techeles

Is there a problem of *tarti d'satri* (contradiction) with combining tekhelet strings dyed according to one view (e.g. half-dyed) with tying methods of a different view?

Comment: Probably depends on the reasons for the given tying method and given number of strings. I don't see how there could be a general answer to this question.

Comment: @DoubleAA specific answers work as well

Comment: Well Rav Hershal Schacter holds like Tosfos with regards to having two blue and two white but holds like the Rambam for tying

Comment: @sam He only sorta holds like Rambam for tying. It's more of a made-up mixture Shittah.

Comment: true but my point is still valid that he mixes shittos